# QPushButton / GPIO on-delay

Tags: python, timer, delay

I am trying to create a GUI for touchscreen light controller for RPi using python. So far I have three QPushButtons on my GUI; one for on/off (single click), one for dimming (long press) and one for led mode change (single click). Each of these control corresponding GPIO to control relay.

For the dimming, my LED requires long signal. If this signal is too short, LED driver considers this as a click and it will work as a on/off switch, which I don't want to happen. For this I need to create some type of script that checks that the QPushButton (name: btn_dim) is pressed longer than x amounts of seconds (let's say 0.5 sec) and then perform desired function (turn GPIO on). Icon on the button should also change when the button is pressed even if the press is shorter than 0.5 sec.

Here's what I got so far:

```
class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.btn_close.clicked.connect(self.appClose)
    self.btn_dim.pressed.connect(self.dimOn)
    self.btn_dim.released.connect(self.dimOff)
    self.iconDIM_off = QtGui.QIcon()
    self.iconDIM_off.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/led/LED-DIM-OFF.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
    self.iconDIM_on = QtGui.QIcon()
    self.iconDIM_on.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("icons/led/LED-DIM-ON.png"))
   
# App close
def appClose(self):
    GPIO.cleanup() 
    sys.exit()


def dimOn(self):
    self.btn_dim.setIcon(self.iconDIM_on)
    t_start = time.perf_counter()
    print(t_start)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    if self.btn_dim.isChecked:
        t_end = time.perf_counter()
        print(t_end)
        t_press = (t_end - t_start)
        print(t_press)
        if t_press > 0.5:
            GPIO.output(5, 0)


def dimOff(self):
    self.btn_dim.setIcon(self.iconDIM_off)
    GPIO.output(5, 1)
```

Now what happens is:

1. Icon changes after 0.5 sec, not immediately
2. Even with a click, GPIO turns on after 0.5 sec and immediately off

How do I modify this, so that the icon changes even with a click/short press, but the GPIO turns on only if the press is longer than 0.5 sec.

Answer (score 0):

Got it work with this:

```
# Dimmer delay to differentiate from click

def dimmerTimer(self):
    time.sleep(0.25)
    start=self.pressed
    end=self.released
    press_time=(end-start)
    if press_time < 0:
        GPIO.output(13, 0)
    else:
        GPIO.output(13, 1)


# Dimmer pushbutton pressed function

def dimPressed(self):
    self.btn_dim.setIcon(self.iconDIM_on)
    self.pressed = time.perf_counter()
    timer = Thread(target=self.dimmerTimer)
    timer.start()


# Dimmer pushbutton released function

def dimReleased(self):
    self.btn_dim.setIcon(self.iconDIM_off)
    self.released = time.perf_counter()
    time.sleep(0.35)
    GPIO.output(13, 1)
```

There's probably better or right way to do this, but this did the trick for me. Hopefully it's helpful to someone!